# What way of fixing pug.js was not found althought i installed by "npm install -g pug" && "npm install -g pug-cli"

Tags: terminal, pug, gulp-uglify

Even though I have the above two commands installed when I run code "pug index.pug --watch". it says not found pug. In addition, I change to use bash in the terminal but it too.
I tried to use Bash, the external terminal, reinstalled new version node.
I was expecting to render code from index.pug to index.html